# USB Device no longer creates /dev entry

Tags: linux, usb, debian, udev

I have a Debian Linux box with a Z-Wave USB stick from Sigma Designs. This has previously been working for just over a year but after a reboot the device is no longer listed in /dev. lsusb and dmesg both still show the device as expected.

How can I get it to show up again?

lsusb output:

```
root@hass:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0658:0200 Sigma Designs, Inc. Aeotec Z-Stick Gen5 (ZW090) - UZB
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

root@hass:~# lsusb -v -d 0658:0200
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0658:0200 Sigma Designs, Inc. Aeotec Z-Stick Gen5 (ZW090) - UZB
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            2 Communications
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x0658 Sigma Designs, Inc.
  idProduct          0x0200 Aeotec Z-Stick Gen5 (ZW090) - UZB
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           0
  iProduct                0
  iSerial                 1 FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0817-1107011516AD
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0043
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iInterface              0
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Call Management:
        bmCapabilities       0x00
        bDataInterface          1
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x00
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        0
        bSlaveInterface         1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              32
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               0
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
root@hass:~#
```

dmesg output when disconnecting and reconnecting the device:

```
[135706.617324] usbip-host 2-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[135765.373065] usb 2-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using uhci_hcd
[135765.997393] usb 2-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0658, idProduct=0200, bcdDevice= 0.00
[135765.997395] usb 2-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=1
[135765.997396] usb 2-2.1: SerialNumber: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0817-1107011516AD
[135766.019503] cdc_acm 2-2.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[135768.374094] usbip-host 2-2.1: usbip-host: register new device (bus 2 dev 9)
```

Answer (score 2):

This was being caused by USBIP, the last line in the dmesg output revealed that the device was automatically being grabbed by a script a few seconds after it was connected.

Disabling this script (and then uninstalling USBIP) fixed the issue.